# codeigniter anchor with image

Tags: image, codeigniter, anchor, base-url

I am trying to use the codeigniter anchor as a link that calls a method to delete a row in my database.

```
<?php echo anchor("masterdata/delete_customer/$row->id",$row->customer_name) ?>
```

This works great but I want to replace the text with an image. something like:

```
<?php echo anchor('masterdata/delete_customer/$row->id',img(array('src'=>'images/delete_icon.png','border'=>'0','alt'=>'Delete'))); ?>
```

The above syntax produces an error:

```
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

In addition, is it possible to replace the masterdata controller path with a base_url path?
baseurl/masterdata/delete_customer...

Many thanks as always,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your example code is the second example uses single quote around the first paramater with the php variable inside. It should be:

```
<?php echo anchor('masterdata/delete_customer/'.$row->id, img(array('src'=>'images/delete_icon.png','border'=>'0','alt'=>'Delete'))); ?>
```

Or swapped to the double quotes.